# Add SSL certificate Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hi have a VPS running Lavarel Sail. I have a domain pointing to my server and I have a SSL certificate (.key) but I don´t know how to add it

S.O.S

Comment: Contact the provider or look at their knowledge base. Nobody can answer your question because it's provider dependent. I have cPanel to upload SSL keys. Or have a look at the knowledge base of DigitalOcean, which is very detailed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.